# Date validation including number of days in respective month

Tags: java, validation, date, datetime

What's the best way to do date validation that includes checking that months are between 1 and 12 and days are between 1 and max. days for the respective month (including leap years)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a compressed and more cleaner way:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    cal.setTime(theConcernedDate);
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Invalid date");
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'm not too keen on using exceptions to validate stuff but I like this as a quick way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to check if the date is valid, you can tweak it (remove useless information)for what you want to use it for

```
try {
            int dayInt = Integer.parseInt(day);
            int monthInt = Integer.parseInt(month);
            int yearInt = Integer.parseInt(year);
            Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            cal.setLenient(false);
            cal.set(yearInt, monthInt-1, dayInt);
            //this will throw an exception if the date is not valid:
            cal.getTime();
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            System.out.println("Invalid date entered.", e);
}
```

also check out the [calender API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for more ways to validate the date